# Undo all mouse event handlers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouse, ads

**NOTE:** the question is about javascript, iOS is used as an example only.

I need to run website hdfull.tv (main page) without the ads which block the first user click and open another ad in a new page instead.

I tried to use `UIWebView` (iOS) because it allows to execute javascript with the following code:

```
document.head.innerHTML = "";
document.body.innerHTML = "";
```

`UIWebView` hides all the content but when I click the page - it still loads ads. I also tried to guess a mouse click event but with no success. Could you help me to cancel these mouse events (or at least find their declarations)? Or maybe could you suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could look into el.removeEventListener(type, callbackFunc) ?

Comment: what do you ask for? hdfull.tv is not my own website if you ask about it

Comment: Can't you just inject JavaScript into the loaded page?

Comment: Yes, I can. But every script I tried doesn't work properly

Comment: So you want to block all the ads and then when they click first time you want to send them to ad ?

Comment: No! Let an user clicked a button on `hdfull.tv`. Page cancels this click and opens ad in another page instead. So the user need to make the second click on a button. I want to change this behaviour to make the user achieving his goal in just one click. Is it more clear now?